# Задать высоту карусели owl-carousel

Tags: html, css

Собственно нужно чтобы на экране был один слайд с фиксированной высотой, как реализовать - не знаю...
Может кто работал с этим скриптом ?
Можно взглянуть на его работу здесь, я пытался сделать но ничего не получилось. http://ravlextest.freeoda.com/

Answer (score 2):

Как это не получилось? Вроде всё понятно - высоту менять в css:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Количество слайдов - при инициализации в js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
  });
});
```